# HTML page in Android Webview

Tags: android, webview

I want to show the static data of a html page in my android Webview.I have path of that html page which is on server.How to show the content.

I am using this code.

```
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        String restUrl = host + url; 

        HttpGet request = new HttpGet(restUrl);

        request.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");

        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);

        responseData = readResponse(response);
```

I m getting response in XML format which is kind of login page. Why it is not displaying the data. I have already login into server.

Comment: It looks like your server require an authentication to access html page ?

Comment: yeah.I think so.But I dont knw how to achieve tht ?